# extreme lag when two views do overlapping drawing

Tags: android

Ok i really have no idea if this is the problem but after a couple of hours of debugging i decided to give it a shot here.

So i have a custom view which i have two instances of in the same ViewGroup. One is bigger than the other (this custom view draws the border of a circle, so my layout is a circle inside a circle). This works fine until i increase the size of the inner view so it draws on the same pixels as the outer view (outer and inner are just a reference to their size, they have the same parent view in the layout hierarchy) when this happens the frame rate om these views drops from >50 to <10. When the inner view comes close to the same size as the outer view the frame rate drops even more, but ones the two views are the same size the frame rate is restored to >50.

This is not part of a scale animation, i change the size of the view statically from code before each run. the frame rate i am referring to is an animation inside the custom view.

Again, i have no idea what the actual problem is, that the lag starts when the views are drawing on the same pixels might be a coincidence. Any advice on how to fix this or even how to debug the problem would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How about a Transitiondrawable?

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/01/implement-fade-out-transition-effect.html

Comment: my custom view is more than just a circle, it was just the easiest way to give a general description of the look of it